# Azure auto-scale VM by time of day

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, scaling, azure-vm-scale-set

I'm new to Azure and auto-scaling and have some questions I have not find answers to.

Today I use a VM and a Service Bus queue. The queue revives jobs only at beginning of each hour during office hours. Because it is important to execute this jobs quickly I want to scale out VM instances before the jobs arrives. And then scale in after the work is done(around 15 minutes later).

In my Service Bus Queue I have a MLQ(multilevel queue). I want to scale in to 1 VM as fast the queue with highest priority is empty.

So, my questions is:
How can I scale out VM instances 10 minutes before each our during office hours? How can I Scale in when the highest prioritized queue is empty? Is using Azure Scale Set a good approach? What techniques can be used to achieve this scaling rules?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Azure Cloud Services (Worker Roles), or VM Availability Sets, or something else?

Comment: I have been testing both soultutions. However, I believe VM Availability Set is the best choice for my case because I need the VMs to run some R-scripts.